# Laravel - Sorting after merging two collections?

Tags: php, mongodb, laravel, collections, eloquent

So I'm trying to get some results from two different MongoDB collections and display them in a single list, ordered by date.

I have the following code:

```
$res=DB::collection('database_saver_mysql')
    ->orderBy('date','desc')
    ->get();

$res2=DB::colection('database_saver_postgres')
    ->orderBy('date','desc')
    ->get();

$merged=$res->merge($res2);
return response($merged);
```

As expected, this displays one list after the other, both being ordered. However, I'd like them to be mixed together and sorted, i.e., I want to sort the $merged collection.

How could I go about doing this? I've tried sortBy() with no luck.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can sort the resulting collection like this:

```
$sorted = $merged->sort();
```

Or if you want to do it by a certain field:

```
$sorted = $merged->sortBy('date');
```

Answer (score 0):

After merged, reset the key values and sort.

```
return $merged->values()->sortBy('date');
```